# Need suggestions to make Regex for string like 5000,5000-2000,5000

Tags: regex

There are 2 parts in my string, either 5 numbers or 5 numbers followed by another 5 numbers with dash in between.

For examples:

```
12345,54321-74185,78945
54321-12345,12345,12345-54321
12345
65432-54321
```

i want to form a regex to exactly match this string.
if user enters for examples like this:

```
12345-54321,5000
2000,50000-20000
20000-50000,12345
```

It shouldn't be matched.
I have already tried this

```
(\d{5}),?(\d{5}-\d{5})?,?
```

but it doesn't exactly match.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How many times those groups of 5 numbers repeat ? Is there a limit, or it's arbitrary ?

Comment: Also in your second sample in second group, `2000` is 4 digit number, is that a typo ?

Comment: @GCP that's not type i said it shouldn't be match

Comment: you said `It should be match`, edit it.

Comment: So did the answer yudong provided help ?

Comment: Why should this one not match? `20000-50000,12345`

Comment: `42` is a number, `5` is a *digit* (and a number as well, but I hope you get what I'm trying to say). Five *numbers* could be `756374831415926535927182818284638756345763563456` :-) Bonus question, what's special about that sequence? Hint: Homer would love it.

Comment: why this one should not match: 20000-50000,12345?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a single five digit number or two five digit numbers with a hyphen between:

```
\d{5}(-\d{5})
```

To match a comma-separated list of such values:

```
\d{5}(-\d{5})?(,\d{5}(-\d{5})?)*
```

To perform an exact match on the full string

```
^\d{5}(-\d{5})?(,\d{5}(-\d{5})?)*$
```

Verification:

```js
var regex = /^\d{5}(-\d{5})?(,\d{5}(-\d{5})?)*$/

var strings = [
  '12345,54321-74185,78945',
  '54321-12345,12345,12345-54321',
  '12345',
  '65432-54321',
  '12345-54321,5000',
  '2000,50000-20000',
  '20000-50000,12345'
];

strings.forEach(function (str) {
    console.log(regex.test(str), str);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for repetition of either:

- only 5 digits `\d{5}`
- only 5 digits with dash in between and 5 digits `\d{5}-\d{5}`
- `\d{5}-\d{5}` followed by a repetition of `,\d{5},\d{5}-\d{5}`
- `\d{5}` followed by a repetition of `,\d{5}-\d{5},\d{5}`

Then maybe a regex like this is what you are looking for:

[`^(?:\d{5}-\d{5}(?:,\d{5},\d{5}-\d{5})*|\d{5}(?:,\d{5}-\d{5},\d{5})*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/yNfc4F/1)

**Explanation**

- The beginning of the string `^`
- Match 5 digits `\d{5}`
- An optional non capturing group `(?:`
- Which matches 5 digits with dash in between and 5 digits `\d{5}-\d{5}`
- Followed by a non capturing group `(?:`
- Which matches `,\d{5},\d{5}-\d{5}`
- Close the capturing group `)`
- And repeat zero or more times `*`
- Or `|`
- Match 5 digits `\d{5}`
- Followed by a non capturing group `(?:`
- Which matches `,\d{5}-\d{5},\d{5}`
- Close the capturing group `)`
- And repeat zero or more times `*`
- Close the first non capturing group `)`
- The end of the string `$`